# Surrounding div-element disappears when hiding div-element only in ie7

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

I have page with some nested div-elements representing nested content. The default view is that only the top level is shown:

http://www.form-online.dk/stage/concept+scheme/Myndigheder/#

Works fine in all browsers except ie7 where clicking a top level heading (f.ex. "Ministerier og Folketinget") makes the entire surrounding div disappear. I have validated the page (there's a single or two errors left but I have checked those also).

I have tried to simplify the page by removing elements to see if I could make the problem go away. I succeeded but it made no sense since the problem when away when I removed enough li-elements (didn't matter which).

Maybe I've overlooked something obvious?

Thx.
Rune

Answer (score 0):

Ok - Found the problem. I had an empty div-element in my xsl-code. For some reason IE7 ignores the -part of this element resulting in a wrong configuration of div-elements ultimately leading to the above behavior. Solved the problem by simply adding an empty space like this:

`<div id="dummy-padding"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></div>`

So it had nothing to do with block/none style.